# ASP.net MVC4: Using a different model in a partial view?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I am just learning ASP.net MVC so please bear with me if I am bad at explaining my issue.

Is it possible to use a different model in a partial view than what is being inherited in the view?

My view `Index` currently inherits `LoginModel`, which deals with the authorization of users. Once a user is authorized, I want the `Index` to display the list of `todos` the user has. `todos` are retrieved via LINQ.

So my partial view wants to inherit `System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<todo_moble_oauth.Models.todo>>`, but I get an error when I use this: `The model item passed into the dictionary is of type

```
System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1[todo_moble_oauth.Models.todo]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'todo_moble_oauth.Models.LoginModel'
```

This is my `Index` view

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<todo_moble_oauth.Models.LoginModel>" %>

<section id="loginForm">
    <% if (Request.IsAuthenticated) { %>

        <% Html.RenderPartial("_ListTodos"); %>

    <% } else { %>

        <h1>Todo Mobile</h1>

        <blockquote>Easily store your list of todos using this simple mobile application</blockquote>

        <% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
            <%: Html.AntiForgeryToken() %>
            <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>

                    <%: Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName) %>
                    <p class="validation"><%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName) %></p>
                    <%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName) %>

                    <%: Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password) %>
                    <p class="validation"><%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password) %></p>
                    <%: Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password) %>

                    <label class="checkbox" for="RememberMe">
                        <%: Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe) %>
                        Remember Me?
                    </label>

            <input type="submit" value="Login" />
        <% } %>
    <% } %>
</section>
```

My partial view `_ListTodos` is as follows:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<todo_moble_oauth.Models.todo>>" %>

<% foreach (var item in Model) { %>
      <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.title) %>
      <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.description) %>
<% } %>
```

My `LoginModel` has the following:

```
public class LoginModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
}
```

The `HomeController` `Index()` method:

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // if user is logged in, show todo list
        if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            //var currentUser = Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;
            todosDataContext objLinq = new todosDataContext();
            var todos = objLinq.todos.Select(x => x);
            return View(todos);
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure you can do that:

```
<% Html.Partial("_ListTodos", userTodos); %>
```

Pass the `userTodos` as a parameter to the Partial helper.

The error you're getting is because you're returning a list of todos to the Index page/view with `return View(todos);` inside the `Index` action method. The Index page needs a `LoginModel` object instead of an `IEnumerable` of todo objects.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master"
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<todo_moble_oauth.Models.LoginModel>" %>
```

---

To solve this, you need to change the way you're passing the `todos` though. Since your `Index` page receives a `LoginModel`, you can add a `Todos` property to this class like this:

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "User name")]
public string UserName { get; set; }

[Required]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[Display(Name = "Password")]
public string Password { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
public bool RememberMe { get; set; }

public IEnumerable<todo_moble_oauth.Models.todo> Todos { get; set; }
```

and then, modify your Index action method:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    // if user is logged in, show todo list
    if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        //var currentUser = Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;
        todosDataContext objLinq = new todosDataContext();
        var todos = objLinq.todos.Select(x => x);

        LoginModel model = new LoginModel();
        model.Todos = todos;

        return View(model);
    }

    return View();
}
```

In the view, do this:

```
<% Html.Partial("_ListTodos", Model.Todos); %>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is a nice and detailed solution too. I had to switch `<% Html.Partial("_ListTodos", Model.Todos); %>` to `<% Html.RenderPartial("_ListTodos", Model.Todos); %>` to make it work, but everything is gold now, thanks!

Comment: I had a similar situation but my model structure was a little different and did not require altering since I only needed to create a new instance of the model. For my needs I used this line of code (Razor Syntax):

@Html.Partial("dialogs/_partial-view", new MyObjectModel())