# Asp.Net MVC 5 calling PartialView with a different Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I want to call a PartialView from my Index.cshtml which uses different Model that I want to call PartialView.

My Index.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<myappname.Models.Post>
...
@Html.Partial("_Block")
```

_Block.cshtml

```
@model myappname.Models.RightBlock
<img src="@Model.blockContent" width="330" />
```

Controller.cs

```
...
public PartialViewResult _Block()
    {
        int id = 2;
        RightBlock rb0 = db.RightBlocks.Find(id);

        return PartialView(rb0);
    }
...
```

Please ignore the id because I just want to call it statically, not dynamically.
When I run the Index Page, I get an error:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[myappname.Models.Post]',
>   but this dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'myappname.Models.RightBlock'.

How can I pass different model to call PartialView?
Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.net MVC4: Using a different model in a partial view?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16697942/asp-net-mvc4-using-a-different-model-in-a-partial-view)

Comment: Easier is you can use ViewBag: @{RightBlock obj = ViewBag.RightBlock as myappname.Models.RightBlock;}

Comment: It worked when I use: 'Html.Partial("_Block", new myappname.Models.RightBlock())' but when I add 2 more Blocks, Index page works but shows nothing. Source is like that: <img class=img-responsive /> . No src is defined and rendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Html.Action`

Index.cshtml

```
@Html.Action("Block")
```

Controller.cs

```
public ActionResult Block()
{
   // Your code
   return PartialView("_Block.cshtml");
}
```

Comment: That works! Thank you. Just an edit: return PartialView("_Block") is enough.

Comment: Yes, if it's under one of the default directories that `WebFormViewEngine` searches for a view, you should only need the name of the view instead of the full path (e.g. "_Partial" instead of "/Dir/_Partial.cshtml").